# Submit multiple mpirun programs in sun grid engine

Tags: openmpi, sungridengine, supercomputers

I would like to know how to submit several mpirun programs in one job script file in Sun Grid Engine.

Suppose I have compiled program1, program2, program3 .. program100
and want to run them simultaneously such that each use 16 cpus 
in one job script without making 100 job scripts.

```
mpirun -np 16 program1 &
mpirun -np 16 program2 &
mpirun -np 16 program3 ....
```

How can I distribute nodes to each programs in Sun Grid engine? 
(Can I split hostfile of SGE into 100 and supply them into each mpirun? )

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to implement that use case with SGE is to use array jobs:

```
#$ -cwd
#$ -pe mpi 16
#$ -t 100

mpirun -np $NSLOTS ./program${SGE_TASK_ID}
```

The `-t 100` parameter creates an array job of 100 tasks and each one receives a different value in the `SGE_TASK_ID` environment variable ranging from `1` to `100`.

Splitting the hostfile is undesirable since that could interfere with the integration between the MPI library and the SGE execution and job monitoring mechanisms.

Comment: I tried the array job in SGE and it worked. Array job is  automatically repeating the same job script many times with some name convention. Thank you.